# Android OnClickListener throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-button

A table is being created such that:

```
    TableLayout layout = new TableLayout(this);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(4,5));
    layout.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);

    for(int i=0; i<7; i++) {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++) {
            Button b = new Button(this);
            b.setText("0");
            b.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
            tr.addView(b);
        }
        layout.addView(tr);
    }

    super.setContentView(layout);
```

The `OnClickListener` `buttonListener` is:

```
View.OnClickListener buttonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button thisButton = (Button) findViewById(((Button)v).getId());
        //thisButton.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt((String) thisButton.getText()) + 1));
        thisButton.getText();
    }
};
```

The call to `thisButton.getText()` throws a NullPointerException, and I'm not sure why. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: But I don't see anywhere you have set the ID for the button.

Comment: You have not set the id at the creation time and you are trying get the id from the button so you are getting exception

Comment: Did not see the dynamic creation of button you can put these ids in shared preferences or hashtable.  DynamicMind is correct.  I am right about the casting but not about getting id from the layout.

Comment: try thisButton.getText().toString();

Comment: Thank you all! Stupid error on my part.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One problem in your code.

Have not set id of Button

```
        b.setText("0");
        b.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
        b.setId(i);
```

Comment: @Code Droid Please tell me how its possible "Button thisButton = (Button) findViewById(((Button)v).getId());" to get id without setingID of a object.

Comment: Actually Now that I view the question closer I see these button sare created in a dynamic manner.  So perhaps a HashMap would work.

Comment: If my answer is correct then you should vote it..Thank you @CodeDroid

Comment: Do you think the findViewById will resolve for a dynamically added button?

Comment: While your at it see what you think of my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791027/showing-and-hiding-listview-footer

Answer (score 0):

```
    TableLayout layout = new TableLayout(this);
            layout.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(4,5));
            layout.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);

            for(int i=0; i<7; i++) {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                for(int j=0; j<6; j++) {
                    Button b = new Button(this);
                    b.setText("0");
                    b.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
                    tr.addView(b);
                }
                layout.addView(tr);
            }

            setContentView(layout);
}
     View.OnClickListener buttonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Button btn1 = (Button)v;
                    //thisButton.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt((String) thisButton.getText()) + 1));
                    String name = btn1.getText().toString();                    
                }
            };
```

I have tested this will work.
When you create view dynamically you don't to assgin an id to it.
you work using the object of the view.
I hope it makes sense to all the people who are curious to set id for dynamic buttons.

Answer (score -1):

You may simply get the text from the passed view, instead of recreating a button.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v instanceof Button)
        String text = ((Button) v).getText();
}
```

Comment: When voting down, you may consider adding a comment. It would be helpful for me and others to learn why an answer is wrong.

Comment: Don't assume V is a button, you will crash.

Comment: Well you might crash if the onClick is ever assigned to somethat that is not a button. So its best to check first if it is a button.

Answer (score -1):

Assumption:

1. I can't see anything regarding setting id to button
2. The below line may causing exception:

> Button thisButton = (Button) findViewById(((Button)v).getId());

Why are you doing? Instead you are already passing a view in click action: `View v`

So you can do straight way like:

```
String strText = ((Button) v).getText();
```

Comment: To **downvoters**, care to leave a comment if anything wrong.

Comment: if V is not a button this will crash.  So first cast. Secondly you need to know that its a particular button anyway.

Comment: @Code Droid, See he is obviously trying to increment the number displayed on a button when the user clicks on it, and he is manipulating his buttons in code and not in layout. If he is not using the same listener for any other views, it is perfectly fine to do it this way. Do not consider managing an id, and just do what he have to do with the view. Am I correct?

Comment: yes, but not correct in casting and assuming you will get a button back.

Comment: The comparison will have to be againt numbers maintained somewhere like hashMap ...

Comment: @CodeDroid why have you deleted your answer if you are smart enough.

Answer (score -1):

It mean your thisButton is probably null, because the statement before that was not successful.

Button thisButton = (Button) findViewById(((Button)v).getId());

does not look right. Usually the paramenter inside findViewById() should be a resource id.
such as

Button thisButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

R.id.button is defined by your layout xml.

Comment: jconfus both of us missed that he is creating the button dynamically in a loop so getting from layout is not an option.